# rails 4 radio buttons display extra label I don't want to display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, button

I have multiple radio buttons which are working great (from an array)
here is my code:

```
<%= [1, 2, 3].each do |item| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :date,  item %> <%=item %>
<% end %>
```

And here is the html code generated

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="appointment_Dimanche">Dimanche</label>
  <br>
  <input id="appointment_date_1" name="appointment[date]" type="radio" value="1"> 1
  <input id="appointment_date_2" name="appointment[date]" type="radio" value="2"> 2
  <input id="appointment_date_3" name="appointment[date]" type="radio" value="3"> 3
      [1, 2, 3]      
</div>
```

And here is what I see

[image]

I want to know why it display the array from which I generate the radio buttons.
And I don't want to display it any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
`<% [1, 2, 3].each do |item| %>
 <%= f.radio_button :date,  item %> <%=item %>
 <% end %>` <br>
```

> remove = in <%= [1,2,3].each ...]%>